# getElementsByName on jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, getelementsbyname

When I select an element by name in Javascript, I usually use this code:

```
document.GetElementsByName('pencil')[0]
```

This way, it gets the first element by the name "pencil" and, if I want to get the second, third, etc. I just change the zero with one, and so on.

Now I am trying to do this in jQuery, by using this selector:

```
$('div[name|="pencil"]')
```

obviously this will be an array of divs named "pencil".

How can I make it refer to a particular name as I do with plain javascript? Thank you.

---

I am trying to get its innerHTML by using this code:

```
alert( $('div[name|="ball"]').html()
```

Comment: or $('div[name|="pencil"]').get(0); ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Please check my edit as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method and do it this way:

```
$('div[name="pencil"]').eq(0)
```

I think it reads a little easier.

I'm not sure why you're using the pipe. That would select divs with name="pencil" or name="pencil-".

*Future readers*: You shouldn’t be giving `div` elements `name` attributes anyway; form elements are normally given `name`s, and they should be unique.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div[name|="pencil"]')[0]
```

or

```
$('div[name|="pencil"]:first')
```

or

```
$('div[name|="pencil"]:eq(0)')
```

Comment: You still need `[0]` or `.get(0)` with examples 2 and 3.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd example will return a jQuery object, an array of elements (the array will contain one element). example 2/3 are not the same as your first example.

Comment: I only know one thing that this will select the first element with name|='pencil'